# ArrayList of objects are not setting in new ArrayList object

Tags: android

```
 try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(botResponse.getResponseStringUrl());
                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("value");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {                        
                        JSONObject jo = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String seq = jo.getString("sequenceNo");
                        Log.d("sequenceNo", seq + "iteration" + i);

                        lo = new ListObject();

                        lo.setStaffID(jo.getString("staffID"));
                        lo.setStatus(jo.getString("status"));
                        lo.setSequenceNo(jo.getString("sequenceNo"));
                        lo.setReason(jo.getString("reason"));
                        lo.setFrom(jo.getString("from"));
                        lo.setDays(jo.getString("days"));
                        lo.setLeaveType(jo.getString("leaveType"));
                        lo.setTo(jo.getString("to"));
                        lo.setName(jo.getString("name"));

                        developersLists.add(lo);
                        botresponselist.add(lo);                         
                    }
                    message.setMessageList(botresponselist);
                    message.setDevelopersList(developersLists);

     }
```

developerlist's all multiple values are not setting in message.setDevelopersList. as setDevelopersList is new arraylist created in message class. only first object is getting set not all the object. but object lo is displaying multiple values. Thank you in Advance

Comment: can you post the response and explain what is the botReponse.getResponseStringUrl() doing

Comment: {"value":
[{"staffID":1004,"status":"Pending","sequenceNo":23,"from":"2018-05-05","days":1,"reason":"","to":"2018-05-05","leaveType":"","name":null},
{"staffID":1004,"status":"Pending","sequenceNo":24,"from":"2018-05-09","days":1,"reason":"","to":"2018-05-09","leaveType":"","name":null},
{"staffID":1004,"status":"Pending","sequenceNo":25,"from":"2018-05-30","days":1,"reason":"","to":"2018-05-30","leaveType":"","name":null}],
"status":{"msg":" Success","code":"200"}}.

Comment: botReponse.getResponseStringUrl()  has all json array which contains multiple json objects as above and jo iterates one json object at time. multiple objects are not setting in setMessagelist.

Comment: I have initilized arrayList developerList and created arrayList of messageList in class messages

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating new instance of ListObject and saving in the same variable due to this it will store only one value.
You have to create a new ListObject instance within the for loop.

Just add this in the for loop, instead of declaring the ListObject outside the for loop.

```
 ListObject lo = new ListObject();
```

Comment: I tried as you said but it is still storing first value , but when is print lo it shows all correct value with all iterations. i would appreciate your more solutions